# Java regex, need help with escape characters

Tags: java, regex

My HTML looks like:

```
<td class="price" valign="top"><font color= "blue">&nbsp;&nbsp;$&nbsp;      5.93&nbsp;</font></td>
```

I tried:

```
String result = "";
        Pattern p =  Pattern.compile("\"blue\">&nbsp;&nbsp;$&nbsp;(.*)&nbsp;</font></td>");

        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

        if(m.find())
            result = m.group(1).trim();
```

Doesn't seem to be matching.

Am I missing an escape character?

Comment: Avoid parsing HTML with regular expressions if possible. Use an HTML parser instead.

Comment: No html parsing using regex please.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless escaped at the regex level, `$` means match the end of line.  And to get the single `\` needed to escape the `$` it needs to be escaped in the String literal; i.e. two `\` characters.  So ...

```
... Pattern.compile("\"blue\">&nbsp;&nbsp;\\$&nbsp;(.*)&nbsp;</font></td>");
```

But the folks who commented that you shouldn't use regexes to parse HTML are **absolutely right**!!  Unless you want chronically fragile code, your code should use a strict or non-strict HTML parser.

Comment: I tried using HtmlParser, but got stuck so I am going the regex route!

Comment: @Blankman - I think you should go back to HtmlParser.  Or if the problem is that you have malformed HTML, switch to a non-strict parser like HtmlCleaner.

Comment: here is the htmlParser question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660866/parsing-html-using-htmlparser thanks!

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to escape `$` (I think, with two slashes)?